# Redirecting pages according to the user account type OR using username & password

Tags: javascript, php

I have been working on this `PHP` code, but I am not able to connect them to their specific pages using account type **Dean, Registrar, Incharge of Accounts and Cashier**.

What I tried:

```
<?php include("header.php");
    include("banner.php") ?>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {
            $uname = trim($_POST['uname']);
            $upass = trim($_POST['pass']);

            $h_upass = sha1($upass);
            if ($uname == '' OR $upass == '') {
        }
    ?>
?>   <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Invalid Username and Password!");
    </script>
<?php    
    } else {
        $user = new User();
        $res = $user::AuthenticateUser($uname, $h_upass); 
?>
```

Comment: ***You shouldn't use [SHA1 password hashes](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)***  or ***[MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Additionally your code has syntax error. else condition is not closed with flower brackets.

Comment: Also the `IF` wont do anything as that is closed to early by the `}`

Comment: I also dont see any code that attempts to do anything with the account type. In fact you do not even tell us how you identify the account type

Comment: im practicing php that's why i'm not really familliar with it

Comment: Incomplete question. Where and how are you evaluating the type of user? Where are you performing any action according the user type?

Comment: i haven't add the account type yet.

Comment: I hope you are enjoying your new skill. But SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: Read this: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using header function ?
also if you can use middleware to redirect the user to specific file that will be nice practice.

```
<?php include("header.php");
include("banner.php") ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {

    $uname = trim($_POST['uname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['pass']);

    $h_upass = sha1($upass);
    if ($uname == '' OR $upass == '') {


}
?>
?>    <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Invalid Username and Password!");
                </script>
            <?php

    } else {
        $user = new User();
        $res = $user::AuthenticateUser($uname, $h_upass);
        if($res)
         {  

            if($user->role == "Dean")
            {
             header('Location: Dean.php');
            }else if($user->role == "Dean")
           {
            header('Location: Registrar.php');
             }

         }

       }

?>
```

Comment: How does this answer _connect them to their specific pages using account type Dean, Registrar, Incharge of Accounts and Cashier_ As yet we dont know where/how that information is stored

Comment: I updated my answer if you user model has role set up you can use it to redirect to specific page.

Comment: where should i include the account type?

Comment: Oh and now it has turned into a ___Rabbit Hole question___ Run.. save yourself!